# Routing Between LAN and Wireguard on DD-WRT Router

Tags: linux, routing, linux-networking, wireguard

## TL; DR

I'm trying to route between a local network (192.168.0.0/24) on my router and a Wireguard interface (192.168.2.0/24) on the router. The router can use the Wireguard interface just fine but other hosts on 192.168.0.0/24 cannot. How do I resolve this?

Hopefully someone can help shed some light on what is going on here as I have already invested a number of hours into trying to figure it out!

## Full Explanation

### Network

First I'd like to lay out my network so that the structure is clear. The following hosts are in play:

- `synapse` - The DD-WRT router causing problems.

  - `oet1` (192.168.2.2) - The Wireguard interface which is successfully connected to `axon`.
  - `vlan2` (55.55.55.55) - The WAN interface of the router.
  - `vlan1` (192.168.0.1) - The LAN interface of the router.
- `axon`

  - `eth0` (55.55.55.66) - The WAN interface of the host.
  - `wg0` (192.168.2.1) - The Wireguard interface connected with `synapse`.
- `neon` - A host on the `synapse` 192.168.0.0/24 network.

  - `eth0` (192.168.0.100)

Here's a diagram of this setup (with WAN interfaces excluded)

```
+--------------------+        +---------------------------------+        +--------------------+
|        Neon        |        |             Synapse             |        |        Axon        |
|                    +------->+                                 +-------->                    |
|        eth0        |        |     vlan1             oet1      |        |        wg0         |
|  192.168.0.100/24  +<-------+ 192.168.0.1/24   192.168.2.2/24 +<-------+   192.168.2.1/24   |
|                    |        |                                 |        |                    |
+--------------------+        +---------------------------------+        +--------------------+
```

### Problem

On `synapse`, pings to `axon` get through just fine. Same on `axon`; pings from `axon` to `synapse` are successful.

However, if `neon` attempts to ping `synapse` at 192.168.2.2, nothing gets through. Same with 192.168.2.1 naturally.

Note: One interesting observation in this whole mess is that, while pinging 192.168.2.2 from `neon`, while applying settings in DD-WRT, roughly 1 or 2 packets make it through until the pings stop responding again. This drives me to believe that this is a firewall issue.

### Configurations

Here are some relevant configurations

#### Routes

```
default 0.0.0.0 55.55.55.1  UG  0   WAN
192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0   *   U   0   oet1
192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0   *   U   0   LAN & WLAN
55.55.55.0  255.255.252.0   *   U   0   WAN
```

#### Wireguard Configuration in DD-WRT

[Screenshot of Wireguard Configuration in DD-WRT web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHi5z.png)

Comment: Your issue might be caused by the CVE-2019-14899 Mitigation that is known to break communication between VPN peers and the local network. Try disabling it and see it it works. You can alternatively add `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o br0 -s $(nvram get oet1_ipaddr)/$(nvram get oet1_netmask) -j MASQUERADE` to your firewall commands.

Comment: Also make sure you're using a recent build such as v3.0-r44236. Older builds have bugs and don't do the proper setup.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I ended up moving to OpenWRT. Fixed the issue and the interface was much more intuitive and powerful .